# Angular form control not updating until next click

Tags: angular, settimeout, angular7, formarray

> Sample app at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnvphg

I'm trying to update a `FormArray`'s checkboxes based on other checks.  In essence if the first item is checked, all the other items have to be unchecked.  If they check any other item, the first item has to be unchecked.

If you look at the example above when I check the first item nothing happens.  Only after I uncheck another item do the rest of the checkboxes blank out.  Why is that happening?  I wrapped the control update in a `setTimeout` block which is what I thought was the accepted practice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has nothing to do with formcontrols, you are using them just fine. it causes from `pairwise()` operator. it doesn't emit value until it has two values. that's why nothing happens on first click. so you should provide initial values to `pairwise()` operator. try this;

```js
this.formArray.valueChanges.pipe(
   startWith([false, true, true, true]),
   pairwise()
)
```